# Why the timesyncd client does not receive any reply from the NTP server (time out in reply)?

Tags: networking, lubuntu, ntp, timeout, systemd-timesyncd

In my lubuntu 22.04 is active the service `systemd-timesyncd.service` which starts the daemon `systemd-timesyncd` (see [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-timesyncd.service.html) the documentation). This is the status of this service:

```
> systemctl status systemd-timesyncd

# this is the output of the previous command:
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-07-06 12:21:43 CEST; 2min 54s ago
       Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
   Main PID: 1917 (systemd-timesyn)
     Status: "Idle."
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 2030)
     Memory: 1.3M
        CPU: 201ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service
             └─1917 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd

lug 06 12:21:55 ceia-te systemd-timesyncd[1917]: Timed out waiting for reply from 185.125.190.57:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
lug 06 12:22:05 ceia-te systemd-timesyncd[1917]: Timed out waiting for reply from 185.125.190.58:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
lug 06 12:22:15 ceia-te systemd-timesyncd[1917]: Timed out waiting for reply from 185.125.190.56:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
lug 06 12:22:25 ceia-te systemd-timesyncd[1917]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.94.4:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
```

The output shows that the service is running and tries to connect to the NTP server `ntp.ubuntu.com` but it does not receive any reply (see messages `Timed out waiting for reply from ntp.ubuntu.com`); this server is reachable by ping as we can see by the output of the following command:

```
> ping ntp.ubuntu.com
PING ntp.ubuntu.com (91.189.94.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from pugot.canonical.com (91.189.94.4): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=30.0 ms
64 bytes from pugot.canonical.com (91.189.94.4): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=29.8 ms
64 bytes from pugot.canonical.com (91.189.94.4): icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=29.8 ms
```

The firewall `iptables` is not active:

```
> sudo iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Can someone tell me why the timesyncd client does not receive any reply from the NTP server `ntp.ubuntu.com`?

Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell. Please clarify: How long has it been like this (it might be temporary situation)? You could also try to configure another timeserver in `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`.

Comment: Your Internet service provider may be filtering NTP UDP requests. Please install `ntpdate` and try `ntpdate -q 91.189.94.4` (with _no_ `sudo`).

Comment: @ArturMeinild It is not a temporary situation and I have tried with other server NTP (time1.google.com, time2.google.com, time-a-g.nist.gov, and so on) with the same Time-Out error in the reply.

Comment: @FedKad is probably right, then the problem must be that the NTP request are filtered out on the network. Unfortunately, this situation has *nothing* to do with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem was in the Internet service provider

Thank for your comments. I have tried to connect to **another network** which is able to connect to Internet by an other way respect of the network which I used when I have written the post.
By this other network and without any modification to the configuration file `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf` which is:

```
[Time]
#NTP=
#FallbackNTP=ntp.ubuntu.com
#RootDistanceMaxSec=5
#PollIntervalMinSec=32
#PollIntervalMaxSec=2048
```

the NTP client `systemd timesyncd` can synchronize the system date to the NTP server `ntp.ubuntu.com`.

In fact the status of the service `systemd-timesyncd.service` is the following:

```
systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-07-06 14:12:48 CEST; 46min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
   Main PID: 2065 (systemd-timesyn)
     Status: "Initial synchronization to time server 185.125.190.56:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com)."
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 2030)
     Memory: 1.3M
        CPU: 203ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service
             └─2065 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd

lug 06 14:12:48 ceia-te systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
lug 06 14:12:48 ceia-te systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
lug 06 14:12:13 ceia-te systemd-timesyncd[2065]: Initial synchronization to time server 185.125.190.56:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
```

So without any modification to the lubuntu configuration and without installing any other package the system works correctly.